# Popover button - Css (Colors)

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm having a problem here in solving a problem, I have a popover that takes the information from the database is possible if there is nothing posted in the "note" field, does it change the color of the button?

```
            <td><a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover"
                    data-trigger="focus" title="Observações" data-placement="right"
                    data-content="{{$item->observacao}}">Obs</a>
            </td>
```

Comment: You want to change button color if there is no `note` property on the `$item` record? Did I get that right?

Comment: yes, if not have record .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you could user PHP's [ternary operators](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/even-shorter-ternary-operators-in-php-using/) to check if record has `note` property, like this:

```
class="btn btn-lg btn-{{$item->note ? 'color when item has note" : 'color when item doesnt have note'}}"
```

The `?` operator here acts like `if-else` condition. First expression will be executed if the condition is satisfied, and the second if conidition is not satisfied. Let me know if you need any additional help with this.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code

```
<td>
  <a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg {{empty($item->note)?'btn-info':'btn-danger'}}" 
      role="button" data-toggle="popover"
      data-trigger="focus" title="Observações" data-placement="right"
      data-content="{{$item->observacao}}">Obs</a>
</td>
```

Comment: It didn't work, all the buttons stayed with btn-info

Comment: Work, but now not show text posted in data-content..

Comment: to work I had to put the .js script in html, you know why you're not reading in laravel?